# How to handle http request failure in simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When I try to scrape data from some website using say `$url`  using simple html **DOM** . After few days links get outdated and i get an saying http request failed.So instead of displaying that error.I want to display something else that I want.

For example here is the code :

```
<?
$html=file_get_html($url);
$title=$html->find("stuff that I want to extract",0)->plaintext;
if($title)
{
echo $title;

}
else{
echo 'problem';
}

 ?>
```

In the above example it displays problem only if that data is not found but I need to display problem if I get http request errors too.

Answer (score 2):

error_reporting level is a valid solution. This can throw exceptions and you can use that to handle your errors. There are many reasons why file_get_html might generate warnings, and PHP's manual itself recommends lowering error_reporting.

Or might be this will help you:

`$html = file_get_html($url) or die('this is not a valid url');`

file_get_html returns false if any issue while getting data.

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
if ($html) {
 // code
} else {
 // error
}
```

Use Try-Catch

```
try {
    $html = file_get_html(trim($url)); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

**Suggestion**: Use CURL to get the URL and handle the error response.

Comment: try catch method is not working.It gives me same error message but or die is working because it is displaying text on or die.But the problem is while handling that error I don't want to display a text like or die does istead of that i want to declare a variable which can be done in try catch.But try catch method everytime runs try even though it has error and is not going to catch,